# Bind properties in Swift to NSTextFields

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield

I'm working on a unit converter written in Swift that will automatically display the updated units within the appropriate `NSTextField`s. For this example, if the user inputs minutes into the `minutesField`, the `secondsField` and `hoursField` should automatically update to display the converted values from the properties. Below is an example of the code in my view controller:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var secondsField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var minutesField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var hoursField: NSTextField!

    var sec: Double = 1
    var min: Double = 1
    var hr: Double = 1

    let conv = [[1,     0.0166666666666667, 0.000277777777777778],
                [60,    1,                  0.0166666666666667],
                [3600,  60,                 1]]

    func updateTextFields() {
        secondsField.stringValue = "\(sec)"
        minutesField.stringValue = "\(min)"
        hoursField.stringValue = "\(hr)"
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTextFieldDelegate {

    override func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification) {

        let tag = obj.object?.tag() ?? 0
        let text = obj.object?.stringValue ?? "1"
        let value = Double(text) ?? 1.0

        switch tag {
        case 0:
            // base unit = seconds
            sec = value
            min = value * conv[0][1]
            hr = value * conv[0][2]
        case 1:
            // base unit = minutes
            sec = value * conv[1][0]
            min = value
            hr = value * conv[1][2]
        case 2:
            // base unit = hours
            sec = value * conv[2][0]
            min = value * conv[2][1]
            hr = value
        default:
            "none"
        }
        updateTextFields()
    }    
}
```

The code above updates the text fields but the active field with the input freezes after the first key stroke. For example, if you try to enter `60` into the seconds field, the next key stroke does not do anything. The number `6.0` appears after the first key stroke (see image below). This is likely due to the function that is called after the properties are updated. The properties are updated based on the tag of the active text field.

Is it possible to have a function that will update all the other text fields other than the currently active field?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the delegate?

Comment: @TroyT Are you referring to `NSTextFieldDelegate`? I may be able to use the `controlTextDidChange()` method.

Comment: Yes, that is what delegate I'm referring to. I don't know much about OS X, but you could try `controlTextDidChange`.

Comment: @TroyT If you have a solution using the delegate method, please submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a function that will update all the other text
>   fields other than the currently active field?

Yes. You can connect all text field to the same action.

First connect all your text fields accordingly to your view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var hourField: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var minuteField: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var secondField: NSTextField!
```

Second create a single var to represent your time interval. You can also add a setter / getter to store it automatically to USerDefaults:

```
var timeInterval: TimeInterval {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "timeInterval")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "timeInterval")
    }
}
```

Third create a TimeInterval extension to convert the time from seconds to hour/minute

```
extension TimeInterval {
    var second: Double { return self }
    var minute: Double { return self / 60 }
    var hour:   Double { return self / 3600 }
    var hourToMinute:   Double { return self * 60 }
    var hourToSecond:   Double { return self * 3600 }
    var minuteToHour:   Double { return self / 60 }
    var minuteToSecond: Double { return self * 60 }
}
```

Fourth create the action that will update the other text fields:

```
@IBAction func timeAction(sender: NSTextField) {
    // use guard to convert the field string to Double
    guard let time = Double(sender.stringValue) else { return }
    // switch the field  
    switch sender {
    case hourField:
        // convert / update secondary fields
        minuteField.stringValue = time.hourToMinute.description
        secondField.stringValue = time.hourToSecond.description
        // make it persist through launches
        timeInterval = time * 3600
    case minuteField:
        hourField.stringValue = time.minuteToHour.description
        secondField.stringValue = time.minuteToSecond.description
        timeInterval = time * 60
    default:
        hourField.stringValue = time.hour.description
        minuteField.stringValue = time.minute.description
        timeInterval = time
    }
}
```

Last but not least make sure you load the values next time your view will appear:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    hourField.stringValue = timeInterval.hour.description
    minuteField.stringValue = timeInterval.minute.description
    secondField.stringValue = timeInterval.second.description
}
```

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ocxcc3conwbpiko/hourMinuteSecond.zip?dl=1)

Comment: Thank you for the example but why are you using `NSTimeInterval`?  I'm using time units as an example; eventually, I plan to extend this approach to other units such as mass, length, pressure, etc.

Comment: NSTimeInterval it is just a typealias to Double. The currentTime property returns a NSTimeInterval.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the setting of the text fields' values out of `viewDidLoad()` to a separate method. Call that method from `viewDidLoad()` and also from a `didSet` property observer on your `seconds` property.

You also need to create action methods for when the seconds, minutes, or hours fields are changed. In the action method for the seconds field, set the `seconds` property to `secondsField.floatValue`. Similarly for the other two fields. In the NIB/storyboard, connects the text fields' actions to the corresponding action method on the view controller.

Comment: Just adding `didSet` to the `seconds` property does not do anything. For example, typing a new number in the text field does not set the `seconds` property.

Comment: Yeah, I had neglected the from-UI-to-model direction. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Could you post some example code? I'm getting the wrong results in the text fields.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you tried and explain what results you got and how they're wrong.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code in my question. Let me know what you think. Suggestions for a better approach are also welcome.