# Switching on UIButton title: Expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type 'String?!'

Tags: ios, swift, types, switch-statement, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use a switch in an `@IBAction` method, which is hooked to multiple buttons

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {

        switch sender.currentTitle {
            case "Button1":
                print("Clicked Button1")
            case "Button2":
                print("Clicked Button2")
            default:
                break
        }
```

When I try the above, I get the following error:

> Expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type
>   'String?!'

Comment: Does `switch (sender as! UIButton).currentTitle {` work?

Comment: @EdCottrell You can compare strings directly in Swift, since tests like `==` test for equality, while `===` tests if the objects are the same exact object.

Comment: @EdCottrell yep was using that before, for some reason I felt a switch would be cleaner, so tried to have a go.

Comment: `func buttonClick(sender: UIButton)` and `switch sender.currentTitle!`

Comment: I would just add different tag values to them instead of reading their optional title

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the comment, would love to know what are the pros/cons?

Comment: @LeoDabus Better to use named outlets than tags. Or separate action methods.

Comment: If you are interested where the `!` in `String?!` comes from, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388830/the-strange-behaviour-of-swifts-anyobject.

Comment: @Sulthan http://stackoverflow.com/a/35691147/2303865

Comment: @Sulthan it is OS X but you can understand the logic

Comment: @LeoDabus I do, I use that logic every day :) I only very dislike the usage of tags.

Comment: just use the outlets

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`currentTitle` is an optional so you need to unwrap it. Also, the type of `sender` should be `UIButton` since you are accessing the `currentTitle` property.

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    if let theTitle = sender.currentTitle {
        switch theTitle {
            case "Button1":
                print("Clicked Button1")
            case "Button2":
                print("Clicked Button2")
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I now get `Expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type 'String?'`

Comment: don't forget to mention also it only works because you changed the method parameter from AnyObject to UIButton

Comment: @Andrei Make sure to change the type of sender to `UIButton`

Comment: @MarcKhadpe yep, missed that. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't swift compare a `String` and a `String?` in a switch ? This looks stupid

Comment: @Guig Probably because optionals are actually enums, so it messes with the switch's logic.  If you need to compare a non-optional to an optional switch, you can still do it by adding a ? to the end e.g. `case "Button1"?:`

Comment: But you can compare them with `==` and switch is kind of the same thing right?

Answer (score 2):

Another way of unwrapping `currentTitle` and I think a more elegant one is:

```
switch sender.currentTitle ?? "" { 
    //case statements go here
}
```