# use of controls in Mac OS application

Tags: swift, cocoa

In a view, there are buttons, radio Buttons and some have same IBAction. I would like to know which one was clicked ?
The function resulting to the action has Sender as parameter.
Unfortunately, I don't know the name of Sender.
In other languages like Delphi, we can know the name of the sender with the following instruction: sender as Button).Name. Is there the same in cocoa swift?

Comment: No need to use a tag to identify your sender. You can switch the sender. You can see an example here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35691147/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for the [`NSView.tag`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483248-tag) property:

> An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.

You can give your controls a tag either in code:

```
yourControl.tag = 10
```

or in the storyboard:

[image]

And then you can check the tag of the sender:

```
if sender.tag == 10 {
    // that's yourControl!
}
```

Comment: This solve my question. Do the Sender parameter have other properties or methods ? If yes, where can I read them

Comment: @AlfredKrief `sender` is whatever control sent the action. If it is a button, it's a `NSButton`. If it is a text field, it's a `NSTextField`. It will have whatever properties those classes (and their superclasses) define. You can see their documentation just by googling their class names.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I can use the same props. and Methods for sender and the control.